# EditText Fields don't appear when running the android app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

**This is the app running**

[image]

**This is the layout editing in Android Studio** 
[image]

Now the question, How can I make the layout appear in the app the same way the layout appear in the layout editing in Android Studio? What am I missing?

**The XML code of the layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.recicla.info.reciclainfo.LoginActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/loginUsername"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Nome de usuário"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="26dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/loginPassword"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="136dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRegisterNewUser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Registre-se"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="157dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="193dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: See the "Text" tab at the bottom left of the Android Studio window? Click that and then copy/paste the XML text here in your question.

Comment: Sorry for being too slow in editng the post. My Apologizes.

Comment: try using a fixed height instead of "wrap_content"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't provided constraints to those views so they all go to the coordinates 0,0 (top left). Please read more about how to use the ConstraintLayout [here.](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html)

You can use the vertical Linear Layout which can give you the same layout but is a lot simpler. Also you should try to learn how to position views using XML as that will allow you to create layouts that are more flexible.

Here's your updated code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="8dp"
tools:context="com.recicla.info.reciclainfo.LoginActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/loginUsername"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Nome de usuário"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/loginPassword"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Login" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvRegisterNewUser"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Registre-se" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. The xml is added.

Comment: there is no typo

Comment: I thought there was haha. Anyway I've updated my answer.

Comment: Your xml version worked. Thanks very much for your time and patience. Now it's time to study excessively about Layouts. Thanks!

Comment: You're very welcome. I'm studying too. I was in your position just a few months ago. Keep studying. It's worth it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead of your current xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.recicla.info.reciclainfo.LoginActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/loginUsername"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Nome de usuário"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/loginPassword"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRegisterNewUser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Registre-se" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: No, it did not work. In the device, the app has not changed, but in the android studio, the design has changed and now it looks the same like in the running app.